# Need help figuring out parameters of __isoc9_scanf()

Tags: c, scanf, disassembly

I have some some C code that I'm trying to understand which uses the function `__isoc99_scanf()`. I haven't encountered that function ever before. I looked it up and it turns out that it is some kind of variation of `scanf()`. This is the code:

```c
__isoc99_scanf(&DAT_00400d18,local_78,(undefined4 *)((long)puVar3 + 4));
```

`&DAT_00400d18` is a C string containing the value `"%s"`. `local_78` is an array of unknown data type. `puVar3` is a pointer that points to the last element of that array.

What really confuses me is why does that function call have three parameters? I know that `scanf()` takes two parameters: the first one is the format string. The second one is the memory address to save the date into. However `__isoc99_scanf()` here is invoked with three parameters. I cannot understand why the third parameter is there. The first parameter `&DAT_00400d18` is just `"%s"`, which suggests that the second parameter be a memory location where to save that string. But why do you need the third parameter when it's not even specified in the format string?

This is not my code, I didn't write it. Actually it is a disassembled version of the assembly code for a particular application that I'm trying to debug. But I've never seen `__isoc99_scanf()` before because I only used `scanf()` in my own code.

Comment: Judging from my experience this looks like GHIDRA compilation?

Comment: @Aplet123 Yes it is.

Answer (score 3):

When you compile `scanf`, the compiler automatically translates it to the `__isoc99_scanf` function in libc. If you compile this code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char buf[32];
    scanf("%32s", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

and decompile in GHIDRA, you get:

```c
__isoc99_scanf(&DAT_001007b4,local_38);
```

where `DAT_001007b4` is "%32s" and `local_38` is a buffer. It behaves exactly the same as normal `scanf`. One important thing to keep in mind when using GHIDRA is it doesn't know exactly how many arguments a function should expect, so if a function is being passed in too many arguments, like in your case, you should just ignore the extra arguments since the code will too.

Comment: Late to the party, but question: how do I figure out (talking of Ghidra and a code that I've not written) which (rather how many) parameters to consider and how many to leave out?